# monetdb error - wrong format ( )

Tags: monetdb

I was running a long SQL query in monetdb to create a flat table from normalized tables.  I kicked it off and left for the day.  This morning the query had died with the following:
sql>\< flat.sql
wrong format ( )
sql>

There is no additional information in the log and I have no idea how long it was running before it died.  The sql requires joining several tables together and does have an order by at the end.  Any information that could help with where to start looking would be great.

Comment: could you provide a minimal reproducible example?  make tiny versions of the tables you are joining and see if you reproduce the error, then please post their contents and structure..thanks!

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to respond.  I did find the answer to my question.  The SQL I was running was an insert.  I had a name column that was a concat of first and last name.  As soon as I realized this it made perfect sense that a column organized database would have an issue with this.  Unfortunately the error message was not helpful so it took pulling apart the query to find it.